# Do/While loop creating endless loop combined with setTimeout

Tags: javascript, css, do-while

I can't figure out why this wont work. I'm using inline opacity, so varX grabs fine. But it seems to be creating and endless loop. zIndex change works fine also on its own.  So I must be doing something wrong in do/while.

Goal is to just change z-index once opacity has reached 0.

**HTML**

```
<div class="ribbon_services_body" id="ribbon_services_body_id" style=" opacity:1;">
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
fade();
function fade() {

    setTimeout(function() {
        $("#ribbon_services_body_id").delay(0).animate({"opacity": "0"}, 800);

    },1000); 

    //var x = $('#ribbon_services_body_id').css('opacity');

    do {
        if($('#ribbon_services_body_id').css('opacity') == 0) {
            document.getElementById('ribbon_services_body_id').style.zIndex = "1";
        }
    }
    while ($('#ribbon_services_body_id').css('opacity') > 0.1);
}
```

**CSS**

```
.ribbon_services_body {
    z-index:3;
    display:block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 10vh;
}
```

Comment: Your `x` value will never update because it's not being set/updated in the loop.

Comment: So you mean move it down below do?

Comment: That'd be a good start for sure!

Comment: I would recommend that you use CSS for all styling where possible, by adding / removing classes for example the `z-index` being set to 1 and the animation of opacity can be done also depending on browser support like so `transition: opacity .8s ease` sourced from  http://www.css3.info/preview/css3-transitions/. Don't forget your browser prefixes too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're really doing this in a bad way.  Even if it worked (by moving the setting of "x" to the current opacity inside the loop) you're still burning CPU time in that loop.  Javascript isn't made to work this way because it'll block all other activity for the .8s while the opacity goes down.  Do this instead:

```
$("#ribbon_services_body_id").delay(1000).animate({
   opacity: 0
}, {
   complete: function() {
       document.getElementById('ribbon_services_body_id').style.zIndex = "1";
   },
   duration: 800
});
```

Comment: This is sharp. And I like saving CPU resources.  Drops opacity fine, but doesn't run compete: func

Comment: This is the proper way to perform this in javascript.  Note that I've fixed the code as the "properties to change" and "options" are separate hashes.

Comment: Your change worked perfectly!  Simple and elegant Thanks

Comment: Just remember this general form because it's a very common idiom in javascript.  You don't poll to see if something is completed as it won't work like that unless you're using a series of "setTimeout"s (see Javier Cobos' comments below for more information). Instead, you pass functions around that will run at completion, and even perhaps on error conditions or success conditions.  In animate you can even run other code during updates (step) and some other times. But this is how you do it.  Remember this and you'll do well.

Answer (score 2):

the problem with the endless loop is not going to be solved even if you put the x calculation inside the while loop.

JS is single threaded application meaning that the setTimeout or animate is never going to be executed because you are trapped in the endless loop before exiting the function. You will probably need this function to be calling itself.

To get rid of this endless loop you have to also setTimeout the call to check, dont use a while, use a function that you can call to check the value every certain amount of miliseconds. this way you will be allowing the first settimeout and animate to work.

Basically, you have to avoid blocking the thread. if a function is containing an endless loop, it doesn't matter if you have another function or a settimeout the whole js execution is trapped there. freezing the browser or any js runner.